# Flow of sum of commuting vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I'm trying to understand why the flow of sum of commuting vector fields is the composition of their flows.

This is apparently supposed to be obvious but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1):

This is not obvious. Let $X, Y$ commute, and consider a point where $X\not =0$ (if $X(p)=Y(p)=0$ the flows at $p$ commute). Using the "flow box theorem", we can find a coordinate system $x,y_1,...,y_n$ such that $X= \partial _x$, and $Y= a\partial _x+ b_1\partial _{y_1}++++b_n\partial {y_n}$. The commutation $[X,Y]$ means that $\partial _x a= \partial _x b_i=0$. The flow $\Phi _t$ of $X$ is just $(x,y_1,...y_n)\to (x+t, y_1,...y_n)$ The flow $\Psi _t$ of  $Y$ can be computed $(x,y_1,...y_n)\to (x+\int _0^t a(\psi(u,y))du, \psi(t,y))$, where $\psi(u,y)$ is the flow of the "vertical" vector field $b_1\partial _{y_1}++++b_n\partial {y_n}$ (which is independant of $x$). Then $\Phi _t\circ \Psi _t (x,y)= (x+t+\int _0^t a(\psi(u,y))du, \psi(t,y)).$ Now deriving this formula  for $t=0$ one obtains $ (1+a, b_1,...b_n)= X+Y(0)$ . The same computation proves also that the two flows commute.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone answers in stricter math, but for intuition consider an affine input nonlinear dynamical system:
$ \dot{x} = f(x) + g(x) u $
with state $x$, input $u$ and $f,g$ vector fields. Now you can ask what happens, if I just let the syste do its thing, thus $u=0$. The trajectories of the system are now the flow of $f$. If then you decide to influence the system using your input $u$, you can just "add" that to the autonomous dynamics.

It goes somewhere along the lines of the solution of an inhomogenious diff. eq.: first you look for the general case and then a particular solutionn for the inhomogenious term - and add them.